# RXJava: Result of 'Single.subscribe()' is ignored

Tags: android, rx-java, warnings

I'm learning the basics of RXJava. As you can see I have a small methods that justs checks if two integers are equal or not and returns the result in the form of a single

```
/**
 * This method checks if both online and offline shopping carts have the same number of items
 * @param numberOfItemsInLocalCart The number of items existing in the offline cart
 * @return true if items in both carts match, false otherwise
 */
public static Single<Boolean> run(int numberOfItemsInLocalCart)
{
    return Single.create(emitter ->
            _VolleyService.getInstance().getDataFuture(URLs.Home).subscribe(
                response ->
                {
                    ShoppingCart cart = HTMLParser.getItemsInShoppingCart(response);
                    if(cart.NumberOfElements == numberOfItemsInLocalCart)
                        emitter.onSuccess(true);
                    else
                        emitter.onSuccess(false);
                },
                    emitter::onError));
}
```

I am getting a warning message showing:

```
Result of 'Single.subscribe()' is ignored
```

How could I get rid of this in a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

`Single#subscribe` returns a `Disposable`. Retaining a reference to this allows you to unsubscribe to the result of your `Single` at a later point.

```
var disposable: Disposable? = run(20).subscribe()
//And later, if you're no longer interested in the result of your Single...
disposable?.dispose()
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but what if i need to return a single from a method? I mean i cannot dispose anything after returning a value...

Comment: You can return a `Single` from a method, that's fine - the warning concerns the `Disposable` that is returned after calling `subscribe()` on that Single

Answer (score 0):

While PPartisans answer is correct regarding the warning you receive, the following might be cleaner to convert your observable to a single (there is no need for `Single.create`):

```
public static Single<Boolean> run(int numberOfItemsInLocalCart) {
    return _VolleyService.getInstance().getDataFuture(URLs.Home)
            .map(response -> {
                    ShoppingCart cart = HTMLParser.getItemsInShoppingCart(response);
                    return cart.NumberOfElements == numberOfItemsInLocalCart
            }.singleOrError()
}
```